# Apache configuration 2.4

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd, http

I need to perform the following configuration on my Apache server, version 2.4, with CentOS 7 system.

The instructions I received are as follows:

> Configuring Another Web Server to Serve the Files If another web
>   server is using port 80 on the same server as Centova Cast, you will
>   need to use this method.
>
> This method depends upon your knowledge of the other web server you
>   are using; you must be familiar enough with your web server of choice
>   to configure it appropriately. Centova Technologies cannot provide
>   support or assistance with any changes to your web server's
>   configuration.
>
> To allow "Let's Encrypt" to validate your domain ownership, you must
>   configure your web server such that any requests for files under the
>   following URI (replacing example.com with your own domain name):
>
> http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ ...are configured to
>   serve files from the following directory:
>
> /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges/ So for example, if you
>   create a file called
>   /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges/test.txt, you should be
>   able to visit http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt
>   in your browser and see the contents of the test.txt file.
>
> A few example configurations are provided below. Please note, however,
>   that differences in your web server configuration may require
>   additional settings not mentioned here.

```
Example apache:

Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges
<Directory /usr/local/centovacast/etc/ssl/acme-challenges>
Options None
AllowOverride None

Apache 2.x
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfModule>

Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all granted
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I've tried everything and I can't get it to work, how should the correct configuration be done?

My configuration file is located at: **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. Please provide an error message or a log excerpt.
You might be running into a problem with SELinux or basic permissions.

Comment: @AndreasRogge The problem is that I don't know which file to edit and which change to make to work as requested.

Comment: Can you help me with this change please?